# Matrix Translate Translating Incorrectly

Tags: android, android-imageview, matrix-transform

I am working ImageView and Matrix translation right now. I try translating an image with this code.

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postTranslate(0, 0);

view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

with above code, the ImageView show with top left image at the top left of the screen (number 1). and then I try to change translate value to `matrix.postTranslate(-1280, -960);` what I expect (number 3) is the image show outside of the screen because the image dimension is 1280 x 960 px. but the result is like the image below (number 2).

[image]

*Black rectangle is what shown in the screen of my device.

My question is why translating image to -1280,-960 only moving the image to the center? Is the translating unit not pixel? or am I making mistake here?
My device is Samsung Note 3 Neo with resolution 720 x 1280 pixels.

Comment: Log.d getDrawable(), also log its intrinsic size

Comment: oh, i try that and the intrinsic size is 2560x1920. This explain why the translate going wrong. But, can you explain what makes the intrinsic size is different? is that because the device dpi?

Comment: where is the png/jpg located under res/drawable* ?

Comment: yes, I make drawable folder inside res folder and put it there

Comment: where exactly?  res/drawable-???

Comment: just "drawable". I make new folder named "drawable".

Comment: place it in drawable-nodpi